# Condition for no solution and infinite no of solutions to a first order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Let $P,Q$ and $R$ are continuous functions of $x,y,u$ and consider the first order PDE:
$$
Pu_x+Qu_y=R,
$$
such that $u=g$ on a curve $\Gamma$ where $u=u(x,y)$ solves the above PDE.

Is there any condition when the above equation have no solution and have infinite no of solutions?

I know if $\Gamma$ satisfies the non-characteristic condition (or transversility condition), then it has unique solution.

But, I am unable to find any condition for which it has no or infinite no of solutions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: There are infinitely many/no solutions to $u_x(x,y)=0$ with $\Gamma=\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb R\}$ a characteristic, depending on if $u|_{\Gamma}$ is constant or not

Comment: Can you please explain a bit? Thanks. I found $u(x,y)=(y)$ is a solution. Now if $u(x,0)=c, constant$, then $f(0)=c$. From here how do you say that, it has infinite solutions? Also, if $u(x,0)$ not a constant, how no solution?

Comment: I don't know what $f$ is. but try to find a second solution! E.g. if $f'=0$ then $f=0$ is not the only solution. For the second:  e.g. $u(x,0)=x$. Can you find a solution? Also, can I ask where the problem is from?

Comment: Hi, I meant $u(x,y)=f(y)$ is a solution of $u_x=0$.

Comment: If $u(x,0)=x$, then since $u(x,y)=f(y)$, we get $f(0)=x$ which is a contradiction. So no solution.

Comment: If $u(x,0)=c$, then from $u(x,y)=f(y)$, we get $f(0)=c$, so $u(x,y)=c$ is the only solution. So it is unique. But you mentioned infinitely many. How?

Comment: $f(0)=c$ is correct. But how do you know what $f(1)$ is?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. So, if $u(x,0)=c$, then $u(x,y)=f(y)$ such that $f(0)=c$ will be a solution. Since there are infinitely many such $f$, the number of solution is infinite. Is it what you menat?

Comment: If so, if you are aware, can you please inform , if there is some general formulae to conclude uniqueness, no solution and infinite solutions?

Comment: yes, exactly! :) This is the same for any characteristic curve for your PDE. I just wrote the simplest example but the proof is basically the same

Comment: So, you mean if $u=g$ on $\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is a characteristic curve. Then if $g$ is a constant, there is infinite solutions and if $g$ is a variable, then no solutions?

Comment: No, being constant in $x$ is special for the PDE $u_x=0$

Comment: It would be nice, if you can help me with some reference about a general formula. Thanks.

Comment: Well, its somewhere in Evans PDE, but I don't think he says much more than what I did (or rather, he gives complicated formulas in $N$ dimensions.) Constant in $x$ for $u_x=0$ in the more general case, is that the initial data already has to "match the PDE"

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.